# Refresh/Reload Eureka PushRow's pushed ViewController options with button?

Tags: eureka-forms

I am using Eureka forms in my project.

I have a PushRow that presents the default SelectorViewController with a list of options. In the pushed view, I have added a rightBarButtonItem that points to *locationSelectorAddButton* ... on click, this brings up a UIAlertController that should allow users to add options to *this* pushed controller.

Is it possible, without creating my own custom selector controller, to refresh the current controller with the newly saved options from UserDefaults?

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

func setupForm() {

form
+++ PushRow<String>(K.SESSIONFIELD.location) {
                $0.title = K.SESSIONFIELD.location
                $0.options = defaults.array(forKey: K.SESSIONFIELD.location) as? [String]
                $0.value = sessionResult?.sessionLocation ?? $0.options?.first
            }
                .onPresent { from, to in
                    to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"add_20pt"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: from, action: #selector(self.locationSelectorAddButton(_:)))

            }
}
```

the locationSelectorAddButton is implemented as follows:

```
@objc func locationSelectorAddButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var textField = UITextField()

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Location", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in

            var locArray = self.defaults.array(forKey: K.SESSIONFIELD.location) as? [String]
            locArray?.append(textField.text!)
            self.defaults.set(locArray, forKey: K.SESSIONFIELD.location)

///TODO: somehow refresh the pushed view controller here!!
//            self.form.rowBy(tag: K.SESSIONFIELD.location)?.reload()
//            print("this is the list of locations currently ...\(locArray)")            
//            self.tableView.reloadData()
///
        }

        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Location name ..."
            textField = alertTextField
        }

        alert.addAction(action)

        present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Push row is not reloaded by using tag property. You need to implement the method

> cellUpdate { cell, row in
>                       row.options = (assign value here for updated options)
>               }